# rails, access constant defined in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to Rails, and I want to use a REST service based on an API key. Things work fine if I define the API key as a constant in the controller class.

Some recommend that constants as API keys to be stored in `/config/environment.rb`. I defined the constants there, but I can't access them and get his error `uninitialized constant`.

Is there anything else I have to do, than defining constants? Do I have to include any file?

my  /config/environments.rb file looks like this:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Apis::Application.initialize!

KEY_1 = "aghtbjki"
SHARED_SECRET_1 = "plkjuvfe"
KEY_2 = "ljfebjyf"
```

I added only the last  three lines.

It may be a simple issue, but it is my first project in Rails.

Comment: Where are you accessing the constants from?

Comment: You should ideally put your constants into a module instead of putting them in a "global namespace". Eg. `module Key; KEY_1="abc"; end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use numbers before letters in naming.
Use, for example:

```
KEY_1 = 'abcd'
SHARED_SECRET_1 = '123123'
KEY_2 = '1232412'
```

Comment: Did you restart your app after adding?